# rewrite url for images

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I trying to use the some plugin for show images in popup window.
I tryed Thickbox, fancybox, but not works.

I think the problem in my URL.

This is my code:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("GetSchemaImage", "Hall", new {folderName = @Model.FolderName })' class="fancybox"><img src='@Url.Action("GetSchemaImage", "Hall", new {folderName = @Model.FolderName })'/></a>
```

This is controller's action:

```
public ActionResult GetSchemaImage(string folderName)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderName))
                return new EmptyResult();
            var folder = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SchemasFolder"];
            var path = Path.Combine(folder, folderName);
            var schemaImage = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*").FirstOrDefault(s => s.EndsWith(".png") || s.EndsWith(".jpg"));
            if (schemaImage != null) 
                return File(Path.Combine(path, schemaImage), "image/png");
            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

This is generated markup:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="/Hall/GetSchemaImage?folderName=marineclub"><img src="/Hall/GetSchemaImage?folderName=marineclub"></a>
```

As I said, I think the problem in URL: `/Hall/GetSchemaImage?folderName=marineclub`. The plugin can't understand this.

I think URL must be the following: /Hall/GetSchemaImage/marineclub. 
How can I rewrite my code that the fancybox can work?

This is javascript code:

```
$(function () {            
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({ type: image });
})
```

Big thanks.

**UPDATE:**
This is all routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var entryRoute = new PageEntry("page/{name}/",
                                           new RouteValueDictionary(
                                               new
                                               {
                                                   controller = "DynamicPage",
                                                   action = "Index",
                                                   name = String.Empty
                                               }),
                                               new RouteValueDictionary(new { name = @".+" }),
                                           new MvcRouteHandler());

            routes.Add("display-page",
                       entryRoute);

            routes.MapRoute("Event Overview", "{city}/{type}/{id}",
                            new {city="astana", controller = "BaseEvent", action = "EventOverview"}, new {city = new CityConstraint()});


            routes.MapRoute(
                "Cinema", // Route name
                "{city}/cinema", // URL with parameters
                new { city = "astana", controller = "Cinema", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new { city = new CityConstraint() }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Concert", // Route name
                "{city}/concert", // URL with parameters
                new { city = "astana", controller = "Concert", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new { city = new CityConstraint() }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Club", // Route name
                "{city}/club", // URL with parameters
                new { city = "astana", controller = "Club", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new { city = new CityConstraint() }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Children", // Route name
                "{city}/children", // URL with parameters
                new { city = "astana", controller = "Children", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new { city = new CityConstraint() }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Sport", // Route name
                "{city}/other", // URL with parameters
                new { city = "astana", controller = "Other", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new { city = new CityConstraint() }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Theater", // Route name
                "{city}/theater", // URL with parameters
                new { city = "astana", controller = "Theater", action = "Index" }, // Parameter defaults
                new { city = new CityConstraint() }
            );  


            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });


            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");



            routes.MapRoute(
                "Activate",
                "Account/Activate/{username}/{key}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Account",
                    action = "Activate",
                    username = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    key = UrlParameter.Optional
                });

            routes.MapRoute(
               "ResetPassword",
               "Account/Reset/{email}/{key}",
               new
               {
                   controller = "Account",
                   action = "Reset",
                   email = UrlParameter.Optional,
                   key = UrlParameter.Optional
               });
        }
```

Comment: Could you show the routing code from your `global.asax.cs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want a URL like this : `/Hall/GetSchemaImage/marineclub` you could do **one** of two things:

- Change your **action method** like this so it matches your default route:

  ```
  public ActionResult GetSchemaImage(string id)
  ```

  So now `Hall/GetSchemaImage/marineclub` => `{controller}/{action}/{id}`

**OR**

- Add a **route** to match your controller:

  ```
  routes.MapRoute(
              "ImageStuff", // Route name
              "{controller}/{action}/{folderName}", // URL with parameters
              new { controller = "Hall", action = "GetSchemaImage",
                  folderName = UrlParameter.Optional });
                  //^^ if set optional it will null if not specified.
  ```